# Creating jQuery Datepickers dynamically and highlighting dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I'm trying to create two datepickers dynamically and providing each one an array of dates to highlight, It's working I can see my two datepickers however they have both the same highlighted dates (the last specified dates) even if I'm providing different dates for each one to highlight.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Vehicles Tracking</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" type="text/css"/>
<script src="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var date = new Date();
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
    var disabledDays = new Array();
    disabledDays[0] = ["2014-1-9", "2014-1-10", "2014-1-12", "2014-1-13"];
    disabledDays[1] = ["2014-2-9", "2014-2-10", "2014-2-12", "2014-2-13"];
    for(var i=0; i<2;i++){
        $("#date").append('<input type="text" id="dp'+i+'" />&nbsp;<span id="choseDate'+i+'"></span></br>');
        var fromArrayDisableDays = disabledDays[i];
        $( "#dp"+i).datepicker({ 
        buttonImage: 'images/calendar.gif',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOn: 'both',
        beforeShowDay: function(date){
                 var m = date.getMonth(), d = date.getDate(), y = date.getFullYear();
                 for (i = 0; i < fromArrayDisableDays.length; i++) {
                    if($.inArray(y + '-' + (m+1) + '-' + d,fromArrayDisableDays) != -1) {
                        return [true, 'ui-state-active', ''];
                    }
                }
                return [false];
        },
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $("#choseDate"+i).text(dateText);
         }
    });
    }
});
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="date">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code I'm using is as following and here is a link to test :http://jsfiddle.net/9kLrx/
Can anyone tell me how can I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Your outerloop has i declared local to the loop:

for(var i=0; i<2;i++){
However, your inner loop is using the same i without declaring it as local:

for (i = 0; i < fromArrayDisableDays.length; i++) {
try changing

for (i = 0; i < fromArrayDisableDays.length; i++) {
to

for (var i = 0; i < fromArrayDisableDays.length; i++) {

Comment: Hi, I did the change but same issue the datepickers are still showing this array : disabledDays[1] as highlighted dates.

Comment: No one can help please?